# Padrino doesn't see SCSS

Tags: ruby, sass, padrino

Gemfile:

```
# Component requirements
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'sass'
gem 'haml'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'activerecord', :require => "active_record"
gem 'sqlite3'
# Test requirements
# Padrino Stable Gem
gem 'padrino', '0.10.7'
```

application.haml:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'reset'
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
```

stylesheet are located public/stylesheets/application.scss

Padrino start...

When I refresh page terminal write:

```
DEBUG -      GET (0.0009ms) /stylesheets/application.css?1340975740 - 404 Not Found
[2012-06-29 17:15:40] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

help me please.

Answer (score 4):

My Padrino version is 0.11.2

I create an project with "-c scss" option, as

```
padrino-gen project mainsystem -a mysql -d datamapper -t rspec -s jquery -e haml -c scss -m mocha
```

I have a line "gem 'sass'" in my Gemfile, and also have a file **lib/scss_init.rb** such that

```ruby
module ScssInitializer
  def self.registered(app)
    # Enables support for SCSS template reloading in rack applications.
    # See http://nex-3.com/posts/88-sass-supports-rack for more details.
    # Store SCSS files (by default) within 'app/stylesheets'
    require 'sass/plugin/rack'
    Sass::Plugin.options[:syntax] = :scss
    Sass::Plugin.options[:template_location] = Padrino.root("app/stylesheets")
    Sass::Plugin.options[:css_location] = Padrino.root("public/stylesheets")
    app.use Sass::Plugin::Rack
  end
end
```

I put **app/stylesheets/foo.scss** and acess to localhost:3000/stylesheets/foo.css, **public/stylesheets/default.css** is generated.

Answer (score 1):

for Padrino v. 0.13.1 is a bit different

I created file **config/initializers/sass.rb** just like in smokycat's answer.

```
module ScssInitializer
  def self.registered(app)
    require 'sass/plugin/rack'
    Sass::Plugin.options[:syntax] = :scss
    Sass::Plugin.options[:template_location] = Padrino.root("app/stylesheets")
    Sass::Plugin.options[:css_location] = Padrino.root("public/stylesheets")
    app.use Sass::Plugin::Rack
  end
end
```

but still I had some problems like:

```
ERROR -  NameError - uninitialized constant YourAppName::App::SassInitializer:
  /Users/user/your_app/join/app/app.rb:3:in `<class:App>'
ERROR -  NameError - uninitialized constant YourAppName::App::SassInitializer:
  /Users/user/your_app/join/app/app.rb:3:in `<class:App>'
```

I figure out that you have to add to  **config/boot.rb**:

```
Padrino.dependency_paths.unshift Padrino.root('config/initializers/*.rb')
```

after that sass works with padrino